# System of logic where "this statement is false" can be encoded?

Tags: logic, paradoxes

Is there a system of logic in which "this statement is false" can be encoded?

I'm familiar with the incompleteness theorems, so I know "this statement cannot be proven" can be expressed.  If the system is consistent, then the statement is true but unprovable.  However "this statement is false" evidently has no truth value.  Is there a system of logic where such a statement can be encoded, and how is the statement analyzed?  Does it depend on model theory?

Comment: There's fuzzy logic; you can encode it as an assertion that the probability of truth of the statement is its own completement: $P\equiv 1-P$, which yields that the statement is half-true.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't think that's valid.  (I did upvote though.)  Suppose that - independent of the statement's content - "This statement is true with probability $P = 1 - P$" is true with probability $a$.  If $a = P$ then the statement is true with probability 1/2 and false with probability 1/2.  If it is false, then it asserts $a \neq P = 1/2$ so we have a contradiction.  For all other $a \neq 0$, the statement is true with probability $a$, and in that case it asserts $a = 1/2$ which is a contradiction.  I think $a = 0$ is a solution - in that case the statement is always false.

Comment: A statement closer to the original in fuzzy logic would be "This statement is true with probability 0".  However this hand-waves the mechanism by which the statement refers to itself.

Comment: As a formal system, I don't know how useful such a system would be. If you think of a formal proof as a list of statements in some formal language with encoded justifications attached (e.g. citing an axiom and pointers to other statements.) What would be the use of a justification on line n pointing to itself? And what would be the use of a rule of inference that points to previous or subsequent statement indicating that it is false? Or that it is true?

Comment: @DanChristensen "If you...justifications attached" Yeah, I'm familiar with the notion, a formal proof is a list of judgements (X true, Y false, etc.) with justifications for each one.  I would be expecting a system where "true" and "false" are not the only judgements, but some mutually exclusive judgement can be given to the statement "this statement is false" (or equivalent, as written in the system).  Not sure if it's useful, just wondering if it's possible in some otherwise-useful system.

Comment: "What would be the use of...Or that it is true?" It wouldn't have to point to itself, it could talk about a Godel numbering instead.  The judgement could be "Tr(#X) <=> ~X true" where "Tr" is a predicate that gives the truth value of the statement with a certain Godel number.  From this statement, "X neither true nor false" could be derived.  Just spitballing, really.

Comment: See [Stanford's Liar Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/#LiarShor) for details and references to self-reference and self-referential sentences.

Comment: There is also a full book: Raymond Smullyan, [Diagonalization and Self-Reference (1994)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Diagonalization_and_Self_reference/uH53QgAACAAJ)

Comment: @jcarpenter2 Even if, for some reason, you wanted to have more the 2 truth values, a statement in a formal proof could only be justified by citing an axiom or rule of inference, and pointing as may be required to PREVIOUS statements only.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think any old programming language would work.  You can write "this sentence is false" as a suitable divergent program, for instance `let x :: Bool = not x` in pseudo-Haskell code.  (Recursive definitions are generally allowed in that language, for instance `let x = 1:x` gives an infinite list of 1's)

I'll go ahead and accept my own answer, unless anybody else happens to want to answer this.

Edit: There's a problem with this.  Propositions-as-types lets you view programming languages as systems of (intuitionistic) logic, but the expression I gave is a term, not a type.  I might delete this answer and write a new one, but let me work on this...

Comment: That's quite a stretch to call a programming language "*a system of logic*". On a math board, no less.